# Dúvida com _viewStart no MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho 2 *layouts* (`LayoutPrincipal.cshtml` e `LayoutInterno.cshtml`) para página inicial é outra para a página interna. A página interna vai se repetir então eu fiz a criação do `_ViewStart` que aponta para a página interna e para testar o *layout* eu criei um `controller` e troco o caminho da página na `_viewStart` mas a dúvida é, não consigo ter 2 `_viewStart` e criar 2 `controller` apontando para elas, alguém sabe como funciona neste caso?

Answer (score 1):

Está errado desta forma. A `_ViewStart` só suporta um arquivo de Layout de cada vez.

Para fazer deste jeito (um layout dentro de outro), primeiro você precisa definir o Layout interno como uma *View* normal. Os detalhes mais de dentro dessa *View* devem ser criados usando *Partials*.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode separar a parte principal e interno em `Areas`, assim você consegue usar um `viewStart` diferente para cada área